# Stop plotting predictions beyond data limits LME ggpredict Effects

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Using the 'iris' dataset (sightly modified as below), I plot the results of an LME.

PLEASE NOTE: I am only using the iris dataset as mock data for the purpose of plotting, so please do not critique the appropriateness of this test. I'm not interested in the statistics, rather the plotting.

Using ggpredict function and plotting the results, the plot extends the predictions beyond the range of the data. Is there a systematic way plot predictions only within the range of each faceted data?

I can plot each facet separately, limit the axis per plot manually, and cowplot them back together, but if there is way to say 'predict only to the max. and min. of the data for that group', this would be great.
Given that these are facets of a single model, perhaps not showing the predictions for different groups is in fact misleading, and I should rather create three different models if I only want predictions within those data subsets?

```
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)
glimpse(iris)
df = iris
glimpse(df)


df_ed = df %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = ifelse(Species == "setosa",Sepal.Length+10,Sepal.Length+0))
df_ed = df_ed %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = ifelse(Species == "versicolor",Sepal.Length-3,Sepal.Length+0))
glimpse(df_ed)

m_test = 
  lmer(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * Species +
  (1|Petal.Width), 
  data = df_ed, REML = T)
summary(m_test)


test_plot = ggpredict(m_test, c("Sepal.Length", "Species"), type = "re") %>% plot(rawdata = T, dot.alpha = 0.6, facet = T, alpha = 0.3)
```

[image: Predicting beyond data range]

Comment: There is no reason to use a mixed model, as there is no apparent clustering in present in the `iris` dataset. Anyhow, I think it would better to obtain predictions from `m_test` for a new dataset. In this new dataset, you could specifiy specific values of covariates for which you would like to get predictions.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated to clarify the use of LMEs was not the question. I'd love to the see the code you suggest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the `limit_range` argument (for *ggeffects* versions before 1.3.2 it was `limit.range`) should help you.

Note the new argument names, introduced in *ggeffects* version 1.3.2 (the old argument names still work, though):

```r
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)

data(iris)
m_test <- lmer(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length * Species + (1 | Petal.Width), data = iris)
pr <- ggpredict(m_test, c("Sepal.Length", "Species"), type = "re")
plot(pr, show_data = TRUE, dot_alpha = 0.6, facet = TRUE, alpha = 0.3)
#> Data points may overlap. Use the `jitter` argument to add some amount of
#>   random variation to the location of data points and avoid overplotting.
```

[image]

```r
plot(pr, show_data = TRUE, dot_alpha = 0.6, facet = TRUE, alpha = 0.3, limit_range = TRUE)
#> Data points may overlap. Use the `jitter` argument to add some amount of
#>   random variation to the location of data points and avoid overplotting.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP's comment, I think this will provide a solution. In this example, I use data from the `sleepstudy` dataset that comes with the `lme4` package. First, we have to postulate a mixed model, which I generically call `fit`.

Note that I do not perform any hypothesis test to formally select an appropriate random-effects structure. Of course, this is essential to adequately capture the correlations in the repeated measurements, but falls outside the scope of this post.

```
library(lme4)
library(splines)

# quantiles of Days
quantile(sleepstudy$Days, c(0.05, 0.95))
# 5% 95% 
# 0   9 

# mixed model
fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ ns(Days, df = 2, B = c(0, 9)) +
              (Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy)

# new data.frame for prediction
ND <- with(sleepstudy, expand.grid(Days = seq(0L, 9L, len = 50)))
```

Then, we need a fucntion that enables us to obtain predictions from `fit` for certain values of the covariates. The function `effectPlot_lmer()` takes the following arguments:

- `object`: a character string indicating the `merMod` object that was fitted (the mixed model).
- `ND`: a character string indicating the new `data.frame`, which specifies the values of the covariates for which we want to obtain predictions.
- `orig_data`: a character string specifying the data on which the mixed model was fitted.

```
# function to obtain predicted reaction times
effectPlot_lmer <- function (object, ND, orig_data) {
  form <- formula(object, fixed.only = TRUE)
  namesVars <- all.vars(form)
  betas <- fixef(object)
  V <- vcov(object)
  orig_data <- orig_data[complete.cases(orig_data[namesVars]), ]
  Terms <- delete.response(terms(form))
  mfX <- model.frame(Terms, data = orig_data)
  Terms_new <- attr(mfX, "terms")
  mfX_new <- model.frame(Terms_new, ND, xlev = .getXlevels(Terms, mfX))
  X <- model.matrix(Terms_new, mfX_new)
  pred <- c(X %*% betas)
  ses <- sqrt(diag(X %*% V %*% t(X)))
  ND$pred <- pred
  ND$low <- pred - 1.96 * ses
  ND$upp <- pred + 1.96 * ses
  return(ND)
}
```

Finally, we can make an effect plot with `ggplot`.

```
# effect plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(effectPlot_lmer(fit, ND, orig_data = sleepstudy),
       aes(x = Days, y = pred)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2, colour = 'blue4') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = low, ymax = upp), colour = NA,
              fill = adjustcolor('blue4', 0.2)) +
  theme_bw() + ylab('Expected Reaction (ms)')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to apply the previous solution to the modified iris dataset and to compare with my own solution of this problem.

First, using the `effectPlot_lmer()` function provided by Dion Groothof:

```
obsdata <- df_ed %>% select(Sepal.Length, Species)

effectPlot_lmer(m_test, obsdata, orig_data = df_ed)

ggplot(effectPlot_lmer(m_test, obsdata, orig_data = df_ed),
       aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
           y = pred, 
           colour = Species, 
           fill = Species)) +
  geom_point(data = df_ed, 
             aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), 
             alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = low, ymax = upp), colour = NA, alpha = 0.3) +
  theme_minimal() + labs(x = "Sepal length", y = "Sepal width")
```

Second, using the `predict()` function:

```
res <- predict(m_test, se.fit = TRUE)
iris_pred <- mutate(ungroup(df_ed), 
                   pred = res$fit, 
                   CI_inf = res$fit - 1.96 * res$se.fit,
                   CI_sup = res$fit + 1.96 * res$se.fit)
ggplot(iris_pred, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, 
                      color = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = CI_inf, ymax = CI_sup),
              alpha = 0.3, colour = NA) +
  geom_line(aes(y = pred), linewidth = 1) +
  labs(x = "Sepal length",
       y = "Sepal width") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Although less straightforward, the first solution seems the best one.